# Get the version of underscorejs used

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm building a widget which would be used in different eCommerce sites.

As i'm using underscorejs library, i need to see if underscorejs exists in the parent site and if so what version.

If underscore is already defined in the site and **if the version matches** with the one i used. I would inturn use their own defined underscore and not make a CDN call to load underscorejs for my widget.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily check that with the following

```
if (!window._ || window._.VERSION !== '1.7.0') {
  // Load underscore from CDN
}
```

Comment: Yes. This works Thanks. Couldn't find it in the doc!

Answer (score 1):

> Get the version of underscorejs used

Check the library itself. Most likely it retained the copyright comment on top of the file.

> i need to see if underscorejs exists in the parent site

```
_.VERSION
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern to load library from HTML:

```
<script>
    (window._ && window._.VERSION === '1.7.0') || document.write("<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js'>\x3C/script>");
</script>
```

You can put this script at the beginning to the widget HTML.